# PHP import Google Cloud Platform class

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'd like to use the Google Cloud Vision API with PHP.
Inside my `www` directory I executed the following command line:

```
composer require google/cloud
```

So now inside `www` I have a `vendor/` directory which has the following files/directories:

`autoload.php`, `bin`, `composer`, `firebase`, `google`, `grpc`, `guzzlehttp`, `monolog`, `paragonie`, `psr`, `ramsey`, `rize`

I'd like now to use the Google Vision API in PHP, following this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web?authuser=1#vision-web-detection-php

But I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Cloud\Vision\VisionClient' not found in
```

I tried to add "vendor" when I'm defining the namespace (as my Google files are under vendor)

```
namespace vendor\Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: `require('$path_to/vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: @Sammitch I just added it but i unfortunately still got Class 'Cloud\Vision\VisionClient' not found

Comment: Your error message implies you're using `Cloud\Vision\VisionClient` instead of `Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient`. `vendor` will never be part of any namespace. It's tough to provide any more comprehensive advice on your code seeing as you've not posted any of it.

Comment: @Sammitch working now, thank you sir!